# Find exec sh: Shell variable not getting passed to subshell

Tags: bash, quoting, function, arguments

Here is a simplified code that prints the name of Directory if it contains a Filename with same name as the parent directory and `.md` extension.

```
FIND(){
    find . -type d -exec sh -c '
        for d do
            [ -f "${d}/${d##*/}.md" ] && printf "%s\n" "$d"
        done' find-sh {} +
}


FIND
```

To generalize I want to send the Search term `${d}/${d##*/}.md` as an argument to the `FIND` function, but unfortunately this does not outputs anything:

```
FIND(){
    local SearchTerm="${1}"
    find . -type d -exec sh -c '
        for d do
            [ -f "${SearchTerm}" ] && printf "%s\n" "$d"
        done' find-sh {} +
}

FIND '${d}/${d##*/}.md'
```

I am sure there is some issue with the quotation of the `SearchTerm`. Any hints?

---

I tried: `FIND '\${d}/\${d##*/}.md'` but has no output

Comment: you should export that `SearchTerm` variable, if you want to pass it to child process. Instead of `local SearchTerm=...;`, write `SearchTerm=$1 find ...`.

Comment: notice that you do _not_ need to quote the `$1` in things like `func(){ VAR=$1 find ... ; }`

Comment: And even if you pass it to the subshell, passing `${d}/$...`  still won't work, because the shell does not expand variables recursively.

Comment: @mosvy Yes exporting doesn't help. How can we make this work? I want to generalize this function by passing different `SearchTerm` while invocation of the function. Also, may I ask you why we don't need  to quote `$1` as you wrote in the previous comment.

Comment: You don't need to quote it because split+glob doesn't happen on the right side of a variable assignment; example: `f(){ v=$1 printenv v; }; f '*  *'`. I think that @Philippes' solution, which could be simplified to just `FIND(){ find ... sh -c '... [ -f "'"$1"'" ]  && ...' ...; }` is fine for what you want to achieve, and trying to "improve" it (with eg. backquoting `"`s in the interpolated variable) will only break it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The in-line script that you call is single-quoted (as it should be). This means that the `sh -c` shell will get a script where `"${SearchTerm}"` is unexpanded.  Since that shell does not have a `SearchTerm` variable, its value will be empty.

Since you tagged your question with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you can pass the name of an exported function:

```bash
# Our find function.
# Takes the name of a test function that will be called
# with the pathname of a directory.
myfind () {
    local thetest="$1"

    # Run find, passing the name of the function into the in-line script.
    find . -type d -exec bash -c '
        testfunc=${1:-:}; shift
        for dirpath do
            "$testfunc" "$dirpath" && printf "%s\n" "$dirpath"
        done' bash "$thetest" {} +
}

# Our test function.
test_md_file () {
    [ -f "$1/${1##*/}.md" ]
}
export -f test_md_file

# Run the thing.
myfind test_md_file
```

The `testfunc=${1:-:}` in the code will assign `$1` to `testfunc` if it's available and not empty, otherwise, it will use `:` as the test (a no-op utility that returns true).

Comment: Could you please explain how this solves the code injection vulnerability?

Comment: @Nikhil Instead of allowing the caller to modify the code by passing strings like `. -o "x" ] && sudo reboot || rm files`, this restricts the caller to a simple command with a single parameter.

Answer (score 5):

`"${SearchTerm}"` needs to be outside of the `sh -c '` to get extrapolated, like follows:

```
FIND(){
    local SearchTerm="${1}"
    find . -type d -exec sh -c '
        for d do
            [ -f "'"${SearchTerm}"'" ] && printf "%s\n" "$d"
        done' find-sh {} +
}

FIND '${d}/${d##*/}.md'
```

To explain a little more, we can run a small test :

```
SearchTerm='${d}/${d##*/}.md'
echo 'Before "$SearchTerm" After'
# output : Before "$SearchTerm" After
echo 'Before "'"$SearchTerm"'" After'
# output : Before "${d}/${d##*/}.md" After
```

`'Before "$SearchTerm" After'` is a single string without any parameter expansion because it's all in single quote.

`'Before "'"$SearchTerm"'" After'` is actually three strings joining together :

`'Before "'` # at the end, it's a double quote followed by a single quote

`"$SearchTerm"` # parameter expansion happens here.

`'" After'`  # at the begining, it's a single quote followed by a double quote

Hope it's clearer.

Comment: @Philippe Could you please explain a bit more about how quoting `"'"${SearchTerm}"'"` helps in keeping it outside `sh -c`?

Comment: This introduces a code injection vulnerability as you are modifying the actual script that you're later running.

Comment: I do agree. The solution I gave is what I think he wanted to do, and I assume he has total control of $SearchTerm.

Comment: @Kusalananda, that's clearly what the OP wants, they want to run arbitrary code (at least arbitrary expansions) for each of the selected directories.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, single quotes are not going to be much of a problem there. The user only needs to bear in mind that the argument to `FIND` has to be shell code that is valid within double quotes. `FIND "\$d/it's cool"` would happily return the searchable directories that contain a regular file called `it's cool`. But you'd need `FIND '$d/it\"s cool'` to find directories that contain a `it"s cool` file.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas There are safer ways to achieve the same effect. By using a callback function instead of giving the `sh -c` script a chunk of code, for example.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas You're right, I mixed up the quoting levels.

Comment: @Philippe This also works (from your explanantion): `'Before '"$SearchTerm"' After'`. Do you know if the additional double quotes in `"'"$SearchTerm"'"` unlike `'"$SearchTerm"'` serves some purpose?

Comment: `'Before '"$SearchTerm"' After'` yields `Before $SearchTerm After`, whereas `'Before "'"$SearchTerm"'" After'` yields `Before "$SearchTerm" After`. There is a difference when $SearchTerm contains spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Some alternative approaches to be able to run arbitrary shell code instead of just `[ -f "$d/${d##*/}.md" ]`:

Pass the shell code as the first argument and use `eval` to interpret it:

```
FIND(){
    find . -type d -exec sh -c '
        code=$1; shift
        for d do
            eval "$code" && printf "%s\n" "$d"
        done' find-sh "$1" {} +
}
FIND '[ -f "$d/${d##*/}.doc" ]'
```

Same with an environment variable

```
FIND(){
    CODE=$1 find . -type d -exec sh -c '
        for d do
            eval "$CODE" && printf "%s\n" "$d"
        done' find-sh "$1" {} +
}
FIND 'base=${d##*/}; [ -f "$d/$base.md" ] && [ -f "$d/$base.doc" ]'
```

Of if the shell code to interpret is always going to be `[ -f "something" ]`:

```
FIND(){
    FILE_TEST=$1 find . -type d -exec sh -c '
        for d do
            eval "[ -f \"$FILE_TEST\" ]" && printf "%s\n" "$d"
        done' find-sh "$1" {} +
}
FIND '$d/${d##*/}.doc'
```

Note that if using `zsh`, you can just use its `e` glob qualifier to further qualify the directories (`/`) with an arbitrary shell `e`xpression:

```
print -rC1 ./**/*(ND/e['[ -f $REPLY/$REPLY:t.md ]'])
```

Or with a function:

```
has_md() [ -f $REPLY/$REPLY:t.md ]
print -rC1 ./**/*(ND/+has_md)
```

(`N` for `nullglob`, `D` for `dotglob` to not ignore hidden files and dirs)